# SQL - JOIN more tables instead of IN (subquery)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a users table - contains `id_user` and a few other columns...and then a few other tables storing user connections which always go with a structure `id_user_one, id_user_two, active`, where user can be either `id_user_one` or `id_user_two`. Also note that 2 users can have connections between them in each connection table (e.g. one record in friends table and one record in family table),

And there comes a table with posts (`id_post, id_user, ...some other columns`),

So now I want to get all posts for particular user and users that are connected with him.

So far I have this (213 is a particular id_user),(example connection tables are friends and family, but there could be more of them)

```
SELECT * FROM posts NATURAL JOIN users 
WHERE id_user IN ( 
    SELECT * FROM(
        (SELECT 213 as id_user)
        UNION
        (SELECT id_user FROM friends WHERE (id_user_one=213 OR id_user_two=213) AND active=1)
        UNION
        (SELECT id_user FROM family WHERE (id_user_one=213 OR id_user_two=213) AND active=1)
    ) idList
)
```

**It IS working**, but my question is how to do that using `JOIN`s instead of the `IN(subquery)`?

Or is using the IN(subquery) a more efficient way for this case?

**EDIT:** I made a mistake in my original query:

```
(SELECT id_user FROM friends WHERE (id_user_one=213 OR id_user_two=213) AND active=1)
```

Should be:

```
(SELECT id_user_two as id_user FROM kontakty WHERE id_user_one=213 AND active=1)
    UNION 
(SELECT id_user_one as id_user FROM kontakty WHERE id_user_two=213 AND active=1)
```

...same goes for the "family" part ...so with this knowing and according to the accepted answer I managed to do my final query and I want to share the knowledge so:

**Here is my final solution:**

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p NATURAL JOIN
     users u
WHERE u.id_user = 213 
      OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM friends f 
          WHERE ((f.id_user_one=213 AND f.id_user_two=u.id_user)
                OR
                (f.id_user_two=213 AND f.id_user_one=u.id_user))
                AND 
                f.active = 1
      )
      OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM family f 
          WHERE ((f.id_user_one=213 AND f.id_user_two=u.id_user)
                OR
                (f.id_user_two=213 AND f.id_user_one=u.id_user))
                AND 
                f.active = 1
      )
```

Comment: `WHERE EXISTS (...)` will do the trick.

Comment: BTW: `UNION` returns unique results. Since you aren't using these results for anything except the `IN` clause, there's no reason not to use `UNION ALL`, which should be a tad faster.

Comment: @Mureinik so you think that it is faster to have duplicates in "IN" rather removing those duplicates first?

Comment: @jave.web If `IN` is implemented properly and early-returns on the first occurrence, it should be. Having said that, I did not bench mark this on any recent MySQL version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a mpre efficient query:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p JOIN
     users u
     on p.id_user = u.id_user
WHERE u.id_user = 213 or
      exists (select 1
              from friends f
              where (f.id_user_one=213 OR f.id_user_two=213) and f.active = 1 and
                    u.id_user = f.id_user
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from family f
              where (f.id_user_one = 213 OR f.id_user_two = 213) and f.active = 1 and
                    u.id_user = f.id_user
             );
```

Then, this query will be more efficient with an index on `friends(id_user, active, id_user_one, id_user_two)` and a similar index on `family`.  These indexes "cover" the query, so the original data pages are not needed, only the index.

Switching to `or`s in the `where` clause instead of `union` gives you several benefits.  First, the entire results do not have to be returned to get a match.  Second, the conditions are "short-circuited", so the first matching condition ends the comparisons.  And third (and most importantly), the engine can take advantage of indexes on the table.

I don't think that trying to create a `join` would work better, if the table are properly indexed.

Changing the `natural join` to a `join` doesn't affect performance.  I'm just not a fan of `natural join`, because you cannot see the `join` conditions -- leading to maintenance problems in code over time.

EDIT:

I suspect this is the query that you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p JOIN
     users u
     on p.id_user = u.id_user
WHERE u.id_user = 213 or
      exists (select 1
              from friends f
              where (f.id_user_one=213 OR f.id_user_two=213) and f.active = 1 and
                    (u.id_user = f.id_user_one or u.id_user = f.id_user_two)
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from family f
              where (f.id_user_one = 213 OR f.id_user_two = 213) and f.active = 1 and
                    (u.id_user = f.id_user_one or u.id_user = f.id_user_two)
             );
```

Comment: You are probably right! I made a typo there - id_user select from friends should have been id_user_one as id_user - anyway you are right it is wrong - there should be one more union covering the other posibility this wouldnt work properly, also I am not sure if the other thing wasnt caused by extra query Ive added to it, as for the answer it is answer to this particular question :)

Comment: To your **EDIT**: Yes kind of like that but a little bit different - see my **EDIT** :) , PS: deleted useless comments

Answer (score 0):

Just give the query a name:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
NATURAL JOIN users 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM(
        (SELECT 213 as id_user)
        UNION
        (SELECT id_user FROM friends WHERE (id_user_one=213 OR id_user_two=213) AND active=1)
        UNION
        (SELECT id_user FROM family WHERE (id_user_one=213 OR id_user_two=213) AND active=1)
     ) idList ON idList.id_user = users.id_user
```

Comment: I ment the inner query - the unions, but @Gordon Linoff's answer covered the actual problem, but still thanks.